# Unsupported major.minor version 52 when using JSONArray

Tags: java, json, unsupported-class-version

So my application throws the following error: `org/json/JSONArray : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0-error) question I understand it has to do with my JRE version which, according to the answer given, should be 8 to work correctly.

My problem is I can not use 8 and would like to know what would be the alternative for using JSONArray.

Answer (score 0):

You can ues a previous version of the library that has been compiled with 1.7, or use an alternative library that works with Java <1.8.

If you have access to the source, you can also try compiling it yourself with target 1.7.